# Help Needed on PHP Image Upload, Slice and Give them a link

Tags: php, image, upload, slice

I want to upload an image in PHP and after uploading I need to provide the facility to slice it and give each slice a link (As MAP tag in HTML) to a different page. If anyone know a library or a class that I can use to do so please post a reply. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) will work just fine for you.

As an alternative, [ImageMagick is also available](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).